# if (un) be a monotone bounded sequence, prove that exactly one of l.u.b and g.l.b. of (un) does not belong to (un)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

**My attempt**

Let's assume that the sequence $(u_n)_n$ is both monotone (either increasing or decreasing) and bounded. We need to prove that exactly one of the least upper bound (l.u.b) and greatest lower bound (g.l.b) of the sequence does not belong to the sequence.

First, let's consider the case when the sequence is increasing. Since the sequence is bounded, it has a least upper bound (l.u.b) and a greatest lower bound (g.l.b). We'll show that the l.u.b does not belong to the sequence.

Assume, for contradiction, that the l.u.b belongs to the sequence. Let's denote the l.u.b as $L$. Since $L$ is the l.u.b, it is an upper bound for the sequence $(u_n)_n$. This means that for every term in the sequence, $u_n\leq L$.

However, since the sequence is increasing, we can find a term in the sequence, let's call it $u_{n^*}$, such that $u_{n^*} > L$. This contradicts the assumption that L is an upper bound for the sequence. Therefore, the l.u.b cannot belong to the sequence.

Now let's consider the case when the sequence is decreasing. Similarly, we'll show that the g.l.b does not belong to the sequence.

Assume, for contradiction, that the g.l.b belongs to the sequence. Let's denote the g.l.b as G. Since G is the g.l.b, it is a lower bound for the sequence (un). This means that for every term in the sequence, un ≥ G.

However, since the sequence is decreasing, we can find a term in the sequence, let's call it un*, such that un* < G. This contradicts the assumption that G is a lower bound for the sequence. Therefore, the g.l.b cannot belong to the sequence.

In both cases (increasing and decreasing), we have shown that either the l.u.b or the g.l.b of the sequence does not belong to the sequence. This proves the desired result.

Note that if the sequence is not monotone, then the statement may not hold. In such cases, it is possible for both the l.u.b and g.l.b to belong to the sequence.

Is my proof is write? If wrong, then please prove that question.

Comment: For a constant sequence both lub and glb are in the sequence.

Comment: "monotone increasing" generally means "$x≥y\implies f(x)≥f(y)$", so constants qualify.  Presumably you meant "*strictly* increasing" which would mean $x>y\implies f(x)>f(y)$".

Comment: @lulu Tricky interpretation that is vulnerable to the age of the mathematical textbook being consulted.  I know for a fact that in *days of yore* (e.g. 50 years ago), the phrase *monotonic* represented either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.  See for example "Calculus 2nd Ed." Vol 1, Tom Apostol.  In modern times, the usage has changed, and *usually* monotonically increasing represents non-decreasing, rather than strictly increasing.  However, not all of the Math dinosaurs have died yet, so the issue is still *iffy*.

Comment: @user2661923 Oh, I was definitely taught that "increasing" meant what is now called "strictly increasing"  and that you had to say "non-decreasing" if you meant what's now called "increasing".  But at this point I think the terms are very standardized.  Sufficiently so that, if you want to use them in a different way, you should spell out exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is **NOT OK**. In the middle of the proof, you write a statement that you did not really justify

> However, since the sequence is increasing, we can find a term in the sequence, let's call it $u_{n^*}$, such that $u_{n^*} > L$.

This statement is a unjustified. How do you know this? I mean, in general, it is not true. For example, if $u_n=1-\frac 1n$, and $L=10$, then you cannot find such an $u_{n^*}$. You need to write more clearly how you got $u_{n^*}$ and where it came from.

Furthermore, in your entire proof, you do not really use the fact that $L$ is supposed to be an element of the sequence. Without using that fact, if your proof was valid, it would actually be a proof that a least upper bound of **any** sequence does not exist. Look, here is my proof of that statement:

> **Statement**: For an increasing sequence, the least upper bound cannot exist.
>
> **Proof**: Assume for contradiction that the l.u.b. exists. Let's denote the l.u.b as $L$. Since $L$ is the l.u.b, it is an upper bound
> for the sequence $(u_n)_n$. This means that for every term in the
> sequence, $u_n\leq L$.
>
> However, since the sequence is increasing, we can find a term in the
> sequence, let's call it $u_{n^*}$, such that $u_{n^*} > L$. This
> contradicts the assumption that $L$ is an upper bound for the
> sequence. Therefore, the l.u.b cannot belong to the sequence.

Do you see the absurdity of my conclusion? Yet I am using the very same justification as you in your proof. This should be a clear red flag to you: if your reasoning can be used to prove a false statement, then the reasoning is flawed.

---

In terms of clarity:

**First**, it's nice to be clear that we are talking about **strictly** monotone sequences here. The statement clearly is not true for non-strictly monotone sequences.

**Second**, you use standard mathematical notation which means writing $\inf$ instead of g.l.b. and $\sup$ instead of l.u.b.

**Third**, you should certainly use mathjax to format your proof. See here for a quick guide: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) . MathJax allows you to be more clear in your writing, as currently, when you write un*, it is not clear if you mean $u_{n^*}$ or $u_n^*$. It also makes everything nicer altogether.

Comment: I disagree.  Based on the posting's 2nd paragraph, the posting uses proof by contradiction, assumes that the sequence is strictly increasing and assumes that the sequence contains its own LUB, $~L,~$ and then shows that this causes a contradiction.  The assumption implies that there exists an $~n~$ such that $~L = a_n~$ is an element of the sequence.  However, since the sequence is presumed strictly increasing, this implies that $~a_{n+1} > a_n~$ which contradicts the assumption that $~a_n~$ is an upper bound.  ...What am I missing?

Comment: @user2661923 You are missing the fact that that's not what OP wrote. OP wrote, I quote, " since the sequence is increasing, we can find a term in the sequence, let's call it $u_{n^*}$, such that $u_{n^*} > L$." This is a false statement. Certainly, if OP said that actually, $L=u_n$ and that $n^*=n+1$, then the statement would be a correct proof. But as it stands, the proof is **not** valid. That does not mean that the statement being proven is false, of course.

Comment: @user2661923 "the assumption implies that there exists an  $n$  such that  $L=a_n$  is an element of the sequence" I know that what the assumption applies. But I see no evidence that OP knows that. Remember, the OP is clearly a beginner in the field. For beginners, jumping over steps of a proof is a very bad idea, as it often leads to faulty logic.

Comment: Very nice rebuttal.